# Gulp-sourcemaps returning only returning `source` js file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, source-maps

My sourcemaps are only returning the source value no matter what.

**Broswerify.js**

```
// add custom browserify options here
var customOpts = {
    entries: ['./frontend/js/app.js'],
    debug: true
};
var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var b = watchify(browserify(opts));
b.transform(require("jadeify"), { compileDebug: true, pretty: false });

// add transformations here
// i.e. b.transform(coffeeify);

gulp.task('browserify', bundle); // so you can run `gulp js` to build the file
b.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
b.on('log', gutil.log); // output build logs to terminal

function bundle() {
    return b.bundle()
    // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        // optional, remove if you don't need to buffer file contents
        .pipe(buffer())
        // optional, remove if you dont want sourcemaps
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) // loads map from browserify file
        // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
        .on('end', function () {
            browserSync.reload();
        });
}
```

**main.js.map**

```
{"version":3,"sources":["/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js","/main.js"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;ACAA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;AACA;
```

This of course means that all files are referenced as `main.js` which is less then helpful :(

I am also using browser-sync, but I don't believe this has any effect on sourcemaps.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `gulp-sourcemaps` v2.3.0

Upgraded to v2.6.0 and now its working. I thank you sir